# Find all files in all directories in c++

Tags: c++, file, search, find

I am trying to find all files in all directories, but I don't know how to handle subdirectories. In this code, the code looks trough all subdirs, but I don't know how to jump back. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
__declspec(dllexport) void GetFiles(char* filedir, char* path)
{
    string s[1000];
    string path2 = path;
    UINT index = 0;

    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    DWORD dwError=0;

    StringCchCopy(szDir, MAX_PATH, filedir);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
        return;

    do
    {

        DWORD attributes = ffd.dwFileAttributes;

        if (attributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)
            continue;
        else if (attributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            TCHAR dir2[MAX_PATH];
            path2 = path;
            path2 += ffd.cFileName;
            path2 += "\\*";
            StringCchCopy(dir2, MAX_PATH, path2.c_str());
            SetCurrentDirectory(dir2);
        }
        else
        {
            s[index] = path;
            s[index] += ffd.cFileName;
            index++;
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) >= 0); // needs to jump back if zero

    FindClose(hFind);
}
```

EDIT: functions had the same name which confused the compiler

Comment: Just changing the current directory won't change where `FindFirstFile` and `FindNextFile` search. You can search subdirectories by using the same function recursively, or you can do a breadth first search, but keeping a queue of directories you need to search (in which, when you encounter a directory, you'll just push it into the queue).

Comment: And you may want to guard against "." and "..", as they tend to (actually *will*) cause infinite enumeration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing directory via `SetCurrentDirectory()` use a recursive call on `GetFiles()`. This would require that the caller pass in a reference to an array (or `std::vector<std::string>`) for the list of files to be stored in instead of using the local array `s`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do it is by doing a recursive function.

This would roughly look like something like this in "c" pseudo code

```
void GetFiles( char*** file_path_table, char* dir )
{
   char **file_paths;
   file_paths = getAllFiles( dir );
   foreach( path in file_paths )
   {
       if ( is_directory( path ) )
       {
           GetFiles( file_path_table, path );
       }
       else
       {
           add_file_to_table( file_path_table, path );
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Will `is_directory()` detect symbolic links that point to directories back higher up in the same tree (effectively making your tree a graph)?

Comment: This would be implementation specific and depending on what you want to do. If you want to follow symbolic links, you should place checks to avoid triggering an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the boost [recursive_directory_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-recursive_directory_iterator).

Note: untested (but should look something like this).

```
namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

std::vector<std::string>    filenames;

std::copy(bfs::recursive_directory_iterator("<path>"),
          bfs::recursive_directory_iterator(),
          std::back_inserter(filenames)
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at the directory iterators of boost instead.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

There are examples covering what you are trying to do, and it will work for almost any OS you can think of.

Have a look at example 3. It shows how to loop over all contents of the directory. If you find a new directory you have not seen before, you just do the same on that. There are tests telling you if the file is regular, directory etc so give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a bit of searching through old posts, I guess I've *mentioned* doing a breadth-first search a number of times, but never really posted code to show how to do it. I guess I might as well do that.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// I think MS's names for some things are obnoxious.
const HANDLE HNULL = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
const int A_DIR = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY;

// We'll process a file by printing its path/name
void process(std::string const &path, WIN32_FIND_DATA const &file) { 
    std::cout << path << file.cFileName << "\n";
}

void find_file(std::string const &folder_name, std::string const &fmask) {
    HANDLE finder;          // for FindFirstFile
    WIN32_FIND_DATA file;   // data about current file.
    std::priority_queue<std::string, std::vector<std::string>,
                       std::greater<std::string> > dirs;
    dirs.push(folder_name); // start with passed directory 

    do {
        std::string path = dirs.top();// retrieve directory to search
        dirs.pop();

        if (path[path.size()-1] != '\\')  // normalize the name.
            path += "\\";

        std::string mask = path + fmask;    // create mask for searching

        // traverse a directory. Search for sub-dirs separately, because we 
        // don't want a mask to apply to directory names. "*.cpp" should find
        // "a\b.cpp", even though "a" doesn't match "*.cpp".
        //
        // First search for files:
        if (HNULL==(finder=FindFirstFile(mask.c_str(), &file))) 
            continue;

        do { 
            if (!(file.dwFileAttributes & A_DIR))
                process(path, file);
        } while (FindNextFile(finder, &file));
        FindClose(finder);

        // Then search for subdirectories:
        if (HNULL==(finder=FindFirstFile((path + "*").c_str(), &file)))
            continue;
        do { 
            if ((file.dwFileAttributes & A_DIR) && (file.cFileName[0] != '.'))
                dirs.push(path + file.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFile(finder, &file));
        FindClose(finder);
    } while (!dirs.empty());
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    if (argc > 2)
        find_file(argv[1], argv[2]);
    else
        find_file("C:\\", "*");
    return 0;
}
```